# React-native absolutely positioned elements in scrollview will not display

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to create a series of "flashcards" in a ScrollView for a quiz app for my EMT class. A user should tap on a card, and have it flip over to reveal the answer. There are headings between sets of cards within the ScrollView.

The card animation is achieved via [this container](https://github.com/kevinstumpf/react-native-flip-view), which positions the card absolutely. I can not get the card to appear correctly - it either has no height and doesn't appear at all, appears squished, or, if I removed the absolute positioning by editing the FlipView code, the height is doubled to make room for the front and back.

Demo code, which can be pasted directly into index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import FlipView from 'react-native-flip-view';

const data = [
  { type: 'default', text: 'some text' },
  { type: 'header', text: 'header text'},
  { type: 'default', text: 'some more text'}
];

class TextLine extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isFlipped: false };
  }

  _flip = () => {
    this.setState({isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped});
  }

  _renderCard = (text) => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._flip} style={{backgroundColor: 'green', padding: 10}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 16, padding: 10}}>{text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.type === 'header') {
      return <Text style={{fontSize: 20, padding: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>{this.props.text}</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <FlipView style={{flex: 1}}
            front={this._renderCard('Flip')}
            back={this._renderCard(this.props.text)}
            isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped}
            flipAxies="x"
            />
    );
  }
}

export default class FlipCardTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <ScrollView  contentInset={{top: 0, bottom: 100}}>
          {data.map((val, idx) => <TextLine key={idx} {...val} />)}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FlipCardTest', () => FlipCardTest);
```

Any ideas on how to get the cards to appear correctly? Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docs, here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html

It says "ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work". Try giving it a specific height, or maybe take the height of the window and pass it down.

You could add, `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}` to the ScrollView and that might solve your problem.

In either case, it would be better to not set the height of the ScrollView, but of a parent. So, I would suggest giving the parent View a height.

This thread might be of help: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3422